# Fill columns if selected column names's substrings are same as one column's content's substring in Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Given a dataframe `df1` as follows, for columns list: `ppi_cols = ['PPI_Coal Mining_MoM', 'PPI_Oil & Gas_MoM']`, if I removed `PPI_` and `_MoM`, it will become `ppi_cols = ['Coal Mining', 'Oil & Gas']`, also for column `names`, after removed `PPI:`  and `: YoY`, this column will become to `Industrial Products, Coal Mining, Oil & Gas, Ferrous Metal Mining`:

```
                            names  PPI_Coal Mining_MoM  PPI_Oil & Gas_MoM
0   PPI: Industrial Products: YoY                  NaN                NaN
1           PPI: Coal Mining: YoY                  NaN                NaN
2             PPI: Oil & Gas: YoY                  NaN                NaN
3  PPI: Ferrous Metal Mining: YoY                  NaN                NaN
```

Then I will compare new columns and new content of `names` column, if they are same, then I will fill that cell with `1`.

How could I achieve that in Pandas? Thanks.

My code to create new column by replacing `:`  with `_` and `YoY` with `MoM` for `names` column.

```
df1['new_names'] = df1['names'].str.replace(': ', '_')
df1['new_names'] = df1['new_names'].str.replace('YoY', 'MoM')
```

The expected result:

```
                            names  PPI_Coal Mining_MoM  PPI_Oil & Gas_MoM
0   PPI: Industrial Products: MoM                  NaN                NaN
1           PPI: Coal Mining: MoM                  1.0                NaN
2             PPI: Oil & Gas: MoM                  NaN                1.0
3  PPI: Ferrous Metal Mining: MoM                  NaN                NaN
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is exactly your question?

You can get the 1s using [`pandas.get_dummies`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html), you can slice the columns using the existing empty columns (based on index or index union).

Example 1:

```
pd.get_dummies(df1['new_names'])[df1.columns[1:-1]]
```

output:

```
   PPI_Coal Mining_MoM  PPI_Oil & Gas_MoM
0                    0                  0
1                    1                  0
2                    0                  1
3                    0                  0
```

Example 2:

```
df2 = pd.get_dummies(df1['new_names'])
cols = df1.columns.intersection(df2.columns)
df1[['new_names']].join(df2[cols].replace(0, float('nan')))
```

output:

```
                      new_names  PPI_Coal Mining_MoM  PPI_Oil & Gas_MoM
0   PPI_Industrial Products_MoM                  NaN                NaN
1           PPI_Coal Mining_MoM                  1.0                NaN
2             PPI_Oil & Gas_MoM                  NaN                1.0
3  PPI_Ferrous Metal Mining_MoM                  NaN                NaN
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solutions, i tested, it works but just small issue, if we have more columns in `df1` such as, `id, date` etc, they will not be included in your final output.

Comment: @ahbon yes they will in the second example, just slice what you want in `df1[['A', 'B', 'C']].join(...)`

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
cols = ['PPI_Coal Mining_MoM', 'PPI_Oil & Gas_MoM']

for col in cols:
    df1[col] = df1['new_names'].eq(col).astype(int).replace(0, np.nan)
```

`OUTPUT`

```
                       names       PPI_Coal Mining_MoM  PPI_Oil & Gas_MoM                     new_names
0   PPI: Industrial Products: YoY                  NaN                NaN   PPI_Industrial Products_MoM
1           PPI: Coal Mining: YoY                  1.0                NaN           PPI_Coal Mining_MoM
2             PPI: Oil & Gas: YoY                  NaN                1.0             PPI_Oil & Gas_MoM
3  PPI: Ferrous Metal Mining: YoY                  NaN                NaN  PPI_Ferrous Metal Mining_MoM
```

Answer (score 1):

Compare columns with numpy broadcasting:

```
ppi_cols = ['PPI_Coal Mining_MoM', 'PPI_Oil & Gas_MoM']

a = np.where(df1['new_names'].to_numpy()[:, None] == ppi_cols, 1, np.nan)

#get all columns names without list ppi_cols and `new_names` (if need remove new_names col)
cols = df1.columns.difference(ppi_cols + ['new_names'], sort=False)
df1 = df1[cols].join(pd.DataFrame(a, columns=ppi_cols, index=df1.index))

print (df1)
                            names  PPI_Coal Mining_MoM  PPI_Oil & Gas_MoM
0   PPI: Industrial Products: YoY                  NaN                NaN
1           PPI: Coal Mining: YoY                  1.0                NaN
2             PPI: Oil & Gas: YoY                  NaN                1.0
3  PPI: Ferrous Metal Mining: YoY                  NaN                NaN
```

Comment: Thanks for your helps, i tested it works, but as @mozway's solution, it works but just small issue, if we have more columns in df1 such as, id, date etc, they will not be included in your final output.

Comment: @ahbon - answer was edited.